# Hide mainform only and keep it in taskbar

Tags: hide, c++builder, taskbar, tform, c++builder-xe5

I have a main form being the parent of x number of ToolWindows. I would like to hide the main form but keep it in the taskbar.

When I set the main form's `Visible = false`, it hides and keeps the ToolWindows visible, so far all good. But the icon in the taskbar disappears too.

I want to hide the main form, keep the ToolWindows visible AND keep the Taskbar icon so I can bring the main form back again.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Application.MainFormOnTaskbr` is set to true, which means the `MainForm` owns the Taskbar button.  When a window is on the Taskbar, it is not possible to show/hide the window without affecting its Taskbar button accordingly.  You have three choices:

1. Set `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` to false, so the `Application` window owns the Taskbar button instead of the `MainForm`.  Not advisible on Vista+, as `ShowMainFormOnTaskbar` was introduced to address UI issues in Vista onwards.
2. Create another window that has its own Taskbar button.  You can use a similar technique that `TApplication` uses for its window.
3. Don't hide the `MainForm`, thus its Taskbar button will not hide.  Move the `MainForm` offscreen, or resize it, so the user cannot see it but Windows still can.